# I want to separate the data coming from firebase react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

```
await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("patients")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .collection("appointment")
      .orderBy("dateTime", "asc")
      .get()
      .then((result) => {
        let appointment = result.docs.map((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          const id = doc.id;
          const currentDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
          const dt=new moment(doc.data().dateTime,'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
          if(dt===currentDate){
            return { id, ...data };
          }
        });
        dispatch({ type: GET_APPOINTMENT, appointment });
      });
```

I am trying to do 3 things at once:

- Get all the appointments for today in an object
- Get all appointments after today in an object
- When an appointment passes the current time, I want to delete it from the database

The dateTime data that is coming is a string like this '2021-02-27-4:30'

Comment: Kindly explain what is/are the specific problem/s you are having

Comment: I have an object appointments that have multiple appointment i want like i wrote to return a separate object that have all the appointment that is set to today and another object for the rest

Comment: you keep on explaining what instead of explaining what is/are the specific problem/s you are having with your attempt

Comment: .where('dateTime'.substring(0,10), '==', moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString())
can I get just the date from dateTime? it have a string like this '2021-02-27-5:40' I want to get just the date to do a query